# ld.exe cannot open output file

Tags: c++11, codeblocks, mingw32

i've used CodeBlocks for 8 months and now begins give me problems.
When I compile a file I happen to receive an error that is not given by the compilation itself, but from codeblock.
The error is:`ld.exe cannot open output file  Permission Denied`.
Then I changed the folder thinking it was a problem with the fact that I do not have administrator access so I could not save in certain parts
Then I tried to rebuild and for a while it worked, and the error would not show up,
now she has returned as before because it keeps giving me the same error.Someone has already received this errorand he resolved?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Your program is probably still running in background, or another process is using that file like anti-virus.
Check in task manager, if the program process is still running you get this message.